# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'maketrans'

Tags: python

```
def complement(dna):
    transtable = dna.maketrans('acgtnACGTN', 'tgcanTGCAN')
    return dna.translate(transtable)

import string
dna = raw_input("Enter DNA sequence: ")
print "Reverse Complement is: ", complement(dna)
```

I already checked dir (string) and there is no maketrans.
Is there a way to import maketrans?

Comment: It is required to call maketrans function.
`from string import maketrans`

Comment: It depends on what version of python do you use.

Comment: `transtable = string.maketrans('acgtnACGTN', 'tgcanTGCAN')` wornks on python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for Python 3.4:

```
def complement(dna):
    transtable = dna.maketrans('acgtnACGTN', 'tgcanTGCAN')
    return dna.translate(transtable)

print(complement('TGA'))
```

and this for Python 2.7:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import string

def complement(dna):
    transtable = string.maketrans('acgtnACGTN', 'tgcanTGCAN')
    return dna.translate(transtable)

print(complement('TGA'))
```

This gives you the major Python version you running your script with:

```
import sys

print(sys.version_info.major)
```

Comment: print with () in 2,7 "you make me feel ill"

Comment: @AleksanderGordienko Always do `from __future__ import print_function` if you still need Python 2. Updated my answer.

Comment: Also think about [unicode_literals](http://python-future.org/unicode_literals.html)

Comment: @drosdata You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.